# Error with using \frac in an equation

Tags: fractions

For some reason, when I try to run this code in LaTeX, it gives the error:
File ended while scanning use of \frac

I don't see my mistake.  Also, my editor gives a warning considering the label: Reference 'eq6' on page 4 undefined. I assume it is, because I am using the reference before the label. But I want to name the formula in the text, before giving the formula.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}

\begin{equation} 
D_3 = -10 \log(\frac{P_2(2 f_{1,2} \pm f_{2,1}){P_2({f_1,f_2)})
\label{eq6}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: As it says, you have not closed your first pair of `\frac` braces. Should be `\frac{P_2(2 f_{1,2} \pm f_{2,1})}`

Comment: ... and there is a spurious `{` before `f_1` in the denominator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

As Au101 already pointed out: There was a `}` missing and according to Ian Thompson a `{` too much.  (Sorry Ian, for having missed your comment.)

Also, for this code to compile, you don't need any extra package in your MWE.  Instead the `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` was missing.

To get nicer braces, you should use `\left` and `\right` before the `()`.  Remember: you have to use `\left` and `\right` always in combination.  You can't use the one without the other.  The delimiters though don't have to match.  You can combine `\left(` with `\right\updownarrow`, just to name an example.  Hence, I also added those.

## Example Code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, oneside]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
  D_3 = -10 \log \left(\frac{P_2(2 f_{1,2} \pm f_{2,1})}
     {P_2(f_1,f_2)}\right)
\label{eq6}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: This is a really nice answer (+1) and I appreciate the credit, but I can only take credit for half of the diagnosis, Ian Thompson did the rest :)

Comment: You may also want to point out that the parentheses around the `\frac` expression are strictly optional.

Comment: @Mico, I must confess, that I am not a mathematician.  You are correct, that it seems to be logical, that the log must be acting on the fraction.  But it may also be convenient or even usual in some disciplines.  I can not tell.  It was present in the authors question, so I corrected it.

Comment: @Au101: The comment came while I was typing and coding.  Thank you, that you pointed me at it.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

See the fixes below.  The example includes the same equation using the `mathtools` package which makes it easier to keep track of brackets of various sorts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parens}()
\begin{document}


\begin{equation} 
D_3 = -10 \log(\frac{P_2(2 f_{1,2} \pm f_{2,1})}{P_2(f_1,f_2)})
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation} 
D_3 = -10 \log\parens[\bigg]{\frac{P_2\parens{2 f_{1,2} \pm f_{2,1}}}{P_2\parens{f_1,f_2}}}
\label{eq2}
\end{equation}

Easier not to ef up the brackets with \eqref{eq2} than it is with \eqref{eq1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]